# integrate R with PHP for aligning Sequence

Tags: php, r, alignment

I'm new in php and R.
Users of my web page enter dna or protein sequences in a text area on html form. I want Align these sequences and then do some operation on it.
For Aligning I wrote a script with R and run it in terminal correctly.
But when I call it from php it dosen't Run.

R Script :

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
pure_seq <- args[1]
library(muscle)
muscle(seqs = pure_seq, out = "Align.fasta")
dev.off()\
```

and My php code to call this Script:

```
exec( "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\Rscript.exe  my_rscript.R" .$data);
```

How can I Run alignment via php and R ?

Comment: Just for testing purposes, try and easy exec call, and see if it works...if doesn't then is just that you can't use the command or the exec call fail

Comment: You could consider placing the sequence with the help of `RODBC` into a database and pull this to HTML with the help of PHP. Alternative you can also place it in a temp .cvs file on the server and load this with PHP.

Comment: Check the permissions.

Comment: thanks for your attention but I can run this example http://www.r-bloggers.com/integrating-php-and-r/ simply. but my scrpit dose not Run!!!

Answer (score 0):

I notice a typo at

```
exec( "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\Rscript.exe  my_rscript.R" .$data);
```

whereas at `r-bloggers` quotes are different

```
exec("Rscript my_rscript.R $N").
```

I hope this will fix it